# BLE-RSSI completely noisy signal

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, positioning, rssi

I am working on an app for indoor navigation. I am reading the RSSI-values of three Bluetooth beacons, that I placed in my apartment. The TX signal strength of these beacons is 6 dBm, advertising interval 100 ms. I am using a Motorola G7 Plus, Android Version 10. In the room there is also WLAN (mine and that of the neighbours).

I have done a lot of measurements (with self-made beacons and bought ones) and very often there is such a lot of noise in the received RSSI-values! I read some papers about indoor navigation and I did not see that other developers were having the same problem. I also cannot figure out what causes this noise. E.g. I did measurements outdoors (with only one beacon), without any WLAN in reach and the noise was still present (though less intense). Maybe it´s interference with the Smartphone?

Has anyone of you experienced similar measurements?

[image]

Comment: I believe the jumps you see are when the phone switches the channel to scan on. BLE uses three different advertising channels.

Comment: yes, that was the case, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call this noise, there is clearly a pattern.
Since a myriad of factors can influence the received signal, one can only speculate without further information/measurements.

An example: Bluetooth LE uses three channels for advertising (37, 38 and 39) which are spread over the frequency band. Since the receiver can only receive on one channel at a time, the picture you showed could indicate that the deviations are caused by the different channels/frequencies that find completely different propagation paths in your environment.

The magic word is filtering. You have to average your RSSI measurements over a longer period of time and then use the obtained values to triangulate the position.

Comment: Thank you, I did a little more research and found that this is a common problem with Android: You cannot define on which of the three advertising channels the phone is scanning and you cannot extract the information on which channel the RSSI-value was received. So I have to use a moving average filter over 12 seconds or something. This makes the position esimation really slow but I see no alternative yet.